# How to fix Chrome Time validation error

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to use input type="time". On my page, if I use two of them. The second one gives a validation error on any time I enter unless I leave it empty.

I've tried values like:
05:05
23:15

The result is always:

Please enter a valid value. The field is incomplete or has an invalid date

The associated HTML is

```
<input type="time" name="timeStart" value="13:22" class="timepick form-control" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="16:45">

<input type="text" name="dteEnd" id="dteEnd" value="16-04-2014" class="date form-control" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Data">

<input type="time" name="timeEnd" value="" class="timepick form-control" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="18:00">
```

Comment: I had no problems with http://jsfiddle.net/int32_t/hjp5c/ .  If I set partial value to the second time input (e.g. specify the hour, but no minute), I had the validation error.

Comment: I do have the described problems on the fiddle. I'm wondering if this is some kind of localization issue. I'm on Chrome 34.0.1847.116, English UI, located in Brazil

Comment: I recommend to file a bug. http://crbug.com/new

Comment: I did and they recommended installing Canary. I did and it fixed the problem. However, I'm not comfortable with this, because obviously this could happen to other users as well.

Comment: Still seeing this issue (over a year later). Seems that the time input widget only inserts hh:mm and the input wants hh:mm:ss ... here's a screenshot of an attempted submit after setting the time value http://files.jstark.co/ck9T

Comment: Solution is to add `step=1` attr to the time input element. Found the answer here: http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2015/05/02/error-validating-seconds-in-html5-time-input/